# Two Java pocess on Mule start

Tags: java, tomcat, mule

I had a problem when execute the Mule start command.
I use Mule 3.4 on a personal server.
It will create two Mule Java processes:

```
mule     19748  7.5 34.3 16219856 5666092 ?    Sl   09:17   7:51 java -Dmule.home=/usr/local/mule -Dmule.base=/usr/local/mule -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=TRUE -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -javaagent:/bus/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Xmx14336m -Xms12288m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/mule/lib/endorsed -Djava.library.path=%LD_LIBRARY_PATH%:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot -classpath %MULE_LIB%:/usr/local/mule/conf:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/mule-module-boot-3.4.0.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/mule-module-reboot-3.4.0.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/mule-module-logging-3.4.0.jar -Dwrapper.key=DJDL5E_MvprCU8wC -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=19020 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=2 org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerBootstrap
mule     21250  5.4 23.1 16127708 3821144 ?    Sl   09:26   5:11 java -Dmule.home=/usr/local/mule -Dmule.base=/usr/local/mule -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=TRUE -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -javaagent:/bus/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Xmx14336m -Xms12288m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/mule/lib/endorsed -Djava.library.path=%LD_LIBRARY_PATH%:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot -classpath %MULE_LIB%:/usr/local/mule/conf:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/mule-module-boot-3.4.0.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/mule-module-reboot-3.4.0.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:/usr/local/mule/lib/boot/mule-module-logging-3.4.0.jar -Dwrapper.key=HorrsPz6m0fU8NBF -Dwrapper.port=32001 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=21248 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerBootstrap
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi Enrico Bortolazzi - could you give some more information about what the problem is? For example, do you get an error message when executing either start command? Remember, on this site you're encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your question to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows then this might be it.

You cannot have two instances running if they have been installed as windows services.

So yo will have to run a "mule remove" command from the bin dir to uninstall it as a service, then you should be able to run multiple instances.